# Can one application access the path of a file from another application on the iPhone? 

Tags: ios4

Can one application access the path of a file from another application on the iPhone?

Answer (score 1):

No. It can not.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about one application accessing resources from another or one application modifying another, No. You can, however, access Documents that other applications have created.

To get the Documents path:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsPath = [paths lastObject];
```